# @INC contains "."

Tags: arrays, perl

When I got on my PC today I found an unpleasant surprise. Every day, the first Perl Program I run is a very simple one to make sure everything is working smoothly:

```
use 5.12.4;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $greeting="Hello, World";
print $greeting;
```

Today however, things did not go as planned. I got the following error when trying to run the program: `Can't locate strict.pm in @INC (@INC contains: .)`. @INC did not used to contain a ".". What happened here and how can I fix this?

Comment: Something's reset your include path to be only "current directory".

Comment: @MarcB: So how do I fix this?

Comment: This question is old, but [Perl 5.26 removed the `.` from `@INC` by default](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2017/01/v5-26-removes-dot-from-inc/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The OP is a [crosspost](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=930403).]

"`.`" is always part of `@INC` (except in taint mode), so it's not true that `@INC` did not contain "`.`" before. Furthermore, the presence or absence of "`.`" is not relevant to your problem. The problem is that other paths that should be present are missing.

This problem is caused by `perl`'s inability to access its library directories. Maybe you lost permission to access these directories, or maybe the directories are gone.

Fix the permissions or restore the directories (possibly by reinstalling Perl).

Comment: So any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: @perl.j, It should go without saying, but here goes: Fix the permissions or restore the directories (possibly by reinstalling Perl).

Answer (score 1):

Update to the first sentence of [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) 's answer:

> "." is always part of @INC (except in taint mode)

From [man perlsec](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec#Taint-mode-and-@INC) :

> **Since version 5.26, the current directory isn't included in @INC by
> default.**

Perl 5.26 was released in 2017. Ikegami's answer was from 2011.

This might help others: My issue was taint mode, and I couldn't modify the -T in the shebang line of the program (read-only), so converting the $PERL5LIB paths into a bunch of -I options fixed it for me, e.g.:

```
perl -I `echo $PERL5LIB | sed 's/:/ -I /g'` -T /sbin/readOnlyProgram.pl
```